# Always show hover data on plotly boxplot

Tags: hover, plotly, boxplot

Is there a way to keep the hover text always on on plotly python, specifically for box-plots?

Or maybe any other solution to easily show the values

[image: Boxplot Example]

Comment: HI Ippolito you should considering using [annotations](https://plotly.com/python/text-and-annotations/).