# Show mouse hover info as annotation in a plotly R boxplot

Tags: r, plotly, boxplot

I have several boxplots and I'd like to always show the information of their mouse hover events. I need that because I am generating pdfs of those charts.

This is a reproducible example:

```
library(plotly)
set.seed(1) 
plot_ly(y = ~rnorm(500), type = "box", hoverinfo = 'y') %>%
layout(yaxis = list(hoverformat = '.2f'))
```

First, I tried to keep the hover info always on (when the mouse is not over the chart), which seems not to be possible [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62736042/8060081).

Now I am trying to add the information from the mouse hover as annotations. However, I do not have the information for the annotations upfront because it is generated by the chart (I mean, the quartiles, max, min and mean were generated into the boxplot).

Can I get the max, min and quartiles directly from the chart to use as annotation by any chance?

The expected result should show the information below on the chart even when the mouse is not over it.

[image]

Comment: Could you explain a little more exactly what you're aiming for? I am confused as you say you're generating pdfs but then you're talking about hover events.

Comment: Sure. I am aiming to see on the chart (permanently) the same numbers I see on the mouse hover.  In other words, I don't want to depend on the mouse hover to see the values for q1, median etc on the chart. Hope it clarifies.

Comment: Ok seems like the easiest thing to do would be to calculate the min, median, max etc with `quantile()` beforehand and add those values as annotations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can manually calculate the values that Plotly generates for you, then use annotations to add the text. Alternatively, you can use the values Plotly generated for you and use annotations to add the text. The only problem I foresee is that the text could overlap..for example if the lower fence and the minimum were the same value.

Here's a method to use the data Plotly generated for you. This method uses `htmlwidgets` `onRender()`. I used `toPrecision()` to round the values to 3 significant digits.

```
library(plotly)
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(1) 
fig <- plot_ly(y = ~rnorm(500), type = "box") %>% # you don't need 'hoverinfo' here
  layout(yaxis = list(hoverformat = '.2f'))

fig %>% htmlwidgets::onRender(
  "function(el, x) {   /* call the plot in JS */
  hc = el.calcdata[0][0];    /* extract calculated hovertext */
  Plotly.newPlot(el.id,
  [{y: el.data[0].y, type: 'box', hoverinfo: 'skip'}],
  {yaxis: {zeroline: false}, annotations: [
  {x: .3, y: hc.lf, showarrow: false, xanchor: 'left', /* add each label*/
  text: 'lower fence: ' + hc.lf.toPrecision(3)},
  {x: .3, y: hc.uf, showarrow: false, xanchor: 'left',
  text: 'upper fence: ' + hc.uf.toPrecision(3)},
  {x: .3, y: hc.max, showarrow: false, xanchor: 'left',
  text: 'max: ' + hc.max.toPrecision(3)},
  {x: .3, y: hc.min, showarrow: false, xanchor: 'left',
  text: 'min: ' + hc.min.toPrecision(3)},
  {x: .3, y: hc.med, showarrow: false, xanchor: 'left',
  text: 'median: ' + hc.med.toPrecision(3)},
  {x: .3, y: hc.q1, showarrow: false, xanchor: 'left',
  text: 'q1: ' + hc.q1.toPrecision(3)},
  {x: .3, y: hc.q3, showarrow: false, xanchor: 'left',
  text: 'q3: ' + hc.q3.toPrecision(3)}
  ]} /*end annotations*/
  ) /* regenerate the plot with annotations and no hovertext*/
  }")
```

[image]

Comment: This is cool. Where do these functions come from? For example, with `el.calcdata[0][0]`? Is this in the plotly js documentation?

Comment: When your R code is made into JS to create a Plotly graph, `el`  houses your Plotly graph. This is a literal `<div>` element in HTML. However, because it's the element that houses the Plotly-generated graph, all of the Plotly functions and modules work with the element. `calcdata` is a Plotly module to generate the calculated data for your graph. If you open the graph in your browser, and go to developer tools. In the console, you can type `el = document.querySelector('[id^=htmlwidget-]');`press enter, then type `el.` and you can scroll through the available Plotly functions.

Comment: I didn't answer your question. Sorry about that. No, `el.calcdata` is not in the Plotly documentation for creating graphs. It's in the code to create Plotly objects, though.

Comment: Wow this is great - I can see [here](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/blob/31a564955b60016669cf0293d7b6613a740827b0/shelly/plotlyjs/static/plotlyjs/src/boxes.js) there are a bunch of precalculated attributes. Useful. Also the plotly library has functions like interpolation, which makes sense but I've never considered before. Thanks!

Comment: Fantastic, Kat! Your answer not only solved my problem but also opened a whole new world for me to study. Thank you.

Comment: All of the HTML-rendered output packages have these interesting aspects you can explore, such as Highcharter, VizNetwork, and so on...