# Extracting axis limits from 'dygraphs::dygraph()' and 'plotly::plot_ly()' figures in R

Tags: javascript, r, plotly, dygraphs

I know how to extract axis limits after making a plot with `base` R functions.

```
plot(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, iris)
(Horizontal_Axis_Limits <- par('usr')[1:2])
(Vertical_Axis_Limits <- par('usr')[3:4])
```

There's a good answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7705345/how-can-i-extract-plot-axes-ranges-for-a-ggplot2-object) for `ggplot2` figures, but is there a way to do this same thing when using other packages such as the `dygraphs` package? I know about the `valueRange` argument to the `dygraphs::dyAxis()` function, but I'm not sure if I can somehow use that to extract the axis limits after the graph has already been created. Here's a reproducible example.

```
Time <- seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct('2022-1-1 00:00:00'), as.POSIXct('2022-3-1 00:00:00'), by = '1 h')
Response <- sin(seq_len(length(Time)) / 100) + rnorm(length(Time), 0, 0.25)
Data_Frame <- data.frame(Time = Time, Response = Response)
Data <- xts(x = Data_Frame$Response, order.by = Data_Frame$Time)
(Figure_1 <- dygraphs::dygraph(Data))
```

Here's a `plotly` reproducible example as well. There's a Stack Overflow answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62030735/how-to-obtain-generated-x-axis-and-y-axis-range-in-plotly-plot) that gives an answer to this question for python, but it doesn't provide anything for R.

```
(Figure_2 <- plotly::plot_ly(ggplot2::economics, x = ~date, y = ~pop))
```

Thank you!

Comment: I don't know if there's a way to do it with `plotly` in R - but if there isn't you can 
 always access the underlying javascript object with `htmlwidgets`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74668844/show-mouse-hover-info-as-annotation-in-a-plotly-r-boxplot) answer for an example of the approach. I am not familiar with `dygraphs` but I imagine it would be harder as plots render using canvas rather than svg.

Comment: That's interesting - thanks. I've never written JavaScript code so I wouldn't be able to do that. I'd certainly upvote someone's answer if they wanted to give it a shot!